# PHPExcel moving from coordinated cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

is there a way, how I can move from coordinated cell in excel to next, e.g. on the right side?

Example:
I have located value, that I'm looking for in excel with PHP , let's say it's has coordinates A3 (I have value, that contains it).

How can I move to next one? I need to show value, that is near my found cell, so it would be B3 value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an kind of next/prev function in PHP.

You can use celliterators though, as shown in `28iterator.php` in `/Examples`

Or you can reference cells by column number and row number, allowing you to simply increment/decrement a row or column number

If you're using an actual address such as `A3`, then you need to split the address into row/column, increment the column, then rejoin the values to get the next address, so:

```
$address = 'A3';
$split = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($address);
++$split[0];
$address = implode($split);
echo $address;
```

Comment: I had also same problem. Thanks for such a nice pluging  :)